# Change partial view html while changing object in angular5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I am calling my child component using selector in parent component like partial view.

```
        <selector></selector>
```

In my parent component,I am having

```
     <div *ngIf="pageloadObject">
         ---parent component html

        <child></child>
     <div>
     <div *ngIf="sliderObject">
       ---parent component html

     <child></child>
     <div>
```

-------------child-----------

```
  <div *ngIf="ChildObj">
  </div>
```

After sliding I am changing url and based on url I am assigning "sliderObject" and "ChildObj" value, Its changing parent html under "sliderObject".but not child html.But hits child component after sliding and changing childObj

Can anyone pls help me to fix it.

I used Changedetectorref also and called

```
 this.ref.markForCheck();
```

Then also it does not solved.

Thanks

Comment: You need to add some more code. It's very clear as is

Comment: I think @David meant its NOT very clear. Which we need more context to have any chance at solving your issue.

Comment: Yeah sorry, **not** very clear... and I can't edit my comment anymore :(

Comment: @david I updated my question

Comment: @kamalav that's what they meant when asked for more code. Please add your child component and parent components code where you modify it. Child view code would also be helpful.

Comment: Hi frnds,pls help